# Simple accordion js issue within table

Tags: javascript, html, accordion

I've added a code snippet for a table plugin in my WP site that is supposed to add an accordion under each product row in a table which will display more information when clicked.

The first accordion is working as it should, however all other accordions under each product row do not respond when clicked.

How can I fix this?

```
<script>
var i;
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {  
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle("active");
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (panel.style.display === "table-row") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "table-row";
    }
  });
}
</script>


<tr class="accordion">
<td colspan="100">Find out more about
     <?php global $product;
            echo $product->get_short_description();
      ?>
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="panel">
<td colspan="100">    
      <?php global $product;
            echo $product->get_description();
      ?>

</td>
</tr>
```

---

SNIPPET UPDATE (seems to work see comment)

```js
var i;
var acc = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");
for (i = 0; i < acc.length; i++) {  
    acc[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    /* this.classList.toggle("active") */;
    var panel = this.nextElementSibling;
    
    if (panel.style.display === "table-row") {
      panel.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      panel.style.display = "table-row";
    }
      });
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr class="accordion">
<td>Find out more about 1
     
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="panel">
<td>    
      Panel 1

</td>
</tr>

<tr class="accordion">
<td>Find out more about 2
     
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="panel">
<td>    
      Panel 2

</td>
</tr>

<tr class="accordion">
<td>Find out more about 3
     
</td>
</tr>

<tr class="panel">
<td>    
      Panel 3

</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: I added a runnable snippet of your code to the question and removed the php stuff. Your code seems to work (you have to click twice because there is no default). PHP error? Check your html on client side. Maybe its your CSS. You should not use tables for this because it is considered bad semantics and there are better tools for this (like block elements and css layout features like flex and grid).

Comment: @lupz Thanks for your fast response. I thought that was the case which is frustrating, it doesn't seem like using tables is a good idea. The reason for using a table plugin is that the cell content is pulled from each product individually and therefore each product has its own category and attributes which then become sortable/filterable when added to a table. The table can also be changed to only show specific product categories on specific pages. Is this still possible if using a grid?